# how to load xampp graphical UI?

Tags: xampp, localhost

I just Install Xampp But maybe somewhere i Missed It Because I can't Load Any Xampp GUI. Also The Browsers Is Not Working Local host URL.

Thank you

Comment: XAMPP does not have a GUI since it is basically a webserver setup with a database and a language to code in. You need other tools for maintanance but those depend on the tools themself (mysql query browser for mysql for instance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you want to add a GUI xampp control panel.  To add a GUI xampp control panel see below.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo gedit ~/.local/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop
```

When the text editor opens simply paste the following, close and save.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Exec=sudo -i python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/24/network-wired.svg
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/24/network-wired.svg
```

If you have a problem with executing the program, install `gksu`, and in the forth line, replace `sudo -i` with `gksudo`.  Below is how to install gksu if not installed, since it has been removed from 13.04.

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Look for xampp control panel in dash

Comment: OK first thank you This Worked For Me but after one restart i start xampp with terminal also the GUI but Can't find in Dash?

Answer (score 5):

I found this article very effective on few systems and it is very simple  too :

Xampp has a small python script that creates the GUI we need for controlling the Server

```
sudo /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
```

By running the above command, you can see the following small application
[image: xampp-control-panel]

you will need the python-glade package to run the above command. If you donot have it , install python-glade use the following command

```
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
```

let us create a desktop shortcut for this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Xampp Control Panel
Comment=Start or Stop XAMPP
Exec=gksudo python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Categories=Application;Development;Web
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=0
```

Create a new file named xampp.desktop place the above contents in it and save it.
Change the file permissions so that it can execute.

```
sudo chmod +x xampp.desktop
```

double-click that file, Xampp control panel will open…

[xampp GUI ubuntu 14.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE7FV.png)https://bhargavg.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/xampp-control-panel-gui-in-ubuntu/

Comment: upvote for "install python-glade2", it worked.

Comment: Update for 2019 Ubuntu 18.04 -- had to drop the `gksudo` to make it work...