# How to start xampp GUI

Tags: 14.04, gui, xampp

I am having trouble finding out how to start the expanded GUI. I have found a tutorial on how to start this one `sudo /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel`

[image: mini xampp gui]
But I am not able to find out how to start this one [image: maxed xampp gui]

Comment: You should install LAMP instead of XAMPP http://askubuntu.com/tags/xampp/info

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xampp suddenly requesting 32bit libs](http://askubuntu.com/questions/489872/xampp-suddenly-requesting-32bit-libs)

Comment: As Oli pointed out XAMPP is a terrifying security breach http://askubuntu.com/a/489881/40581

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The primary answer didn't work for me until I did something from [followed of this example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412002/how-to-load-xampp-graphical-ui) which states:

> I believe that you want to add a GUI xampp control panel.  To add a
>   GUI xampp control panel see below.
>
> Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your
>   keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:
>
> ```
> sudo gedit ~/.local/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop
> ```
>
> When the text editor opens simply paste the following, close and save.
>
> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
> Name=XAMPP Control Panel
> Exec=sudo -i python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
> Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/24/network-wired.svg
> Encoding=UTF-8
> Terminal=false
> Name=XAMPP Control Panel
> Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
> Type=Application
> Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/24/network-wired.svg
> ```
>
> If you have a problem with executing the program, install `gksu`, and
>   in the forth line, replace `sudo -i` with `gksudo`.  Below is how to
>
> > install gksu if not installed, since it has been removed from 13.04.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install gksu
> ```
>
> Look for xampp control panel in dash

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Xampp 5.6.3.Then I was able to use what the primary answerer posted. This is the code quote from Kyusuf Muhammad:

> You can use the command below if you use 32 system :
>
> ```
> sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux.run
> ```
>
> if you use 64 system:
>
> ```
> sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
> ```

Answer (score 55):

You can use the command below

if you use 32 system :

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux.run
```

if you use 64 system :

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

Comment: You got my upvote.

Comment: So easy - Mine upvote too :)

Comment: It seems this file is removed in newer versions. Mine is `XAMPP for Linux 5.6.24` and there's no `manager-linux-x64.run` in my `/opt/lampp/` folder

Answer (score 4):

Two important notes to the advice given by @HelpNeeder: there should be a quote around the code the executable, and the image for the default icon for Xampp icon is accessible as `/opt/lampp/htdocs/dashboard/images/xampp-logo.svg`. Copy it into folder `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/24/`

Thus, the final advice is to open a new terminal, run

`sudo gedit ~/.local/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop`

and save the following in the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Exec=gksudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon="/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/24/xampp-logo.svg"
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Type=Application
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

`gedit ~/.local/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Type=Application
Categories=Development
Exec=gksudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
```

You have to install the package `gksu`.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to spit out the GUI is to use the following codes. One after the other.

```
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./manager-linux.run (or manager-linux-x64.run)
```

[Snapshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XvBa.png)

Comment: That's nearly the same as [this answer](/a/551686) except that yours uses an additional `cd` command instead of executing the program directly by its absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking  ,is to create a shortcut to launch the graphical interface. If you so , than I've found the solution :
1)Go to `/opt/lampp` and open terminal and type `sudo chmod 777 manager-linux-x64.run` (for 64-bit) or `sudo chmod 777 manager-linux.run`(For 32 bit).

2)Now go to desktop and create a file named `xampp.desktop` and paste the following :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Exec=sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=true
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Type=Application
```

After that save it and double click on the icon. A pop-up may show up ,in there click on `Make It Trusted` and then run it again. A terminal will open asking for user password. Give it and it will open the Graphical Interface. It worked fine for my `Ubuntu and Linux Mint`...